# Mapping an stxxl::vector to a File with Header

Tags: c++, stxxl

I have a large binary ([STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format))) file that begins with a known and fixed size header and then continues with a bunch of fixed size buffers (PODs) representing consecutive records.

I want to map the record part of the file to an `stxxl::vector` for fast out-of-core processing.
The `stxxl::vector<>` has a ctor that accepts a `stxxl::file`, but I don't know how to tell the ctor to start the file parsing from the correct offset.

Can I do this and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should be possible to implement rather easily.

The stxxl::vector has a constructor which uses a file.
`vector_type v(&f);`

This constructor just makes blocks which references the file blocks by offset.
You could modify this constructor to add an extra header offset.

Comment: That would be great. I'll look into the code to see if I can add this (maybe even make a PR if it works!). Thanks for an amazing library!